# If $X_n \to X$ in Hausdorff distance then does $X_n \cap E \to X \cap E$ in Hausdorff distance?

Tags: general-topology, analysis, metric-spaces

Provided all of the sets mentioned are compact subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$.

I know that $d_{H}(X_n \cap E,X \cap E)$ need **not** be less than or equal to  $d_{H}(X_n,X)$ but that alone does not seem to be enough to disprove the claim (if it is false).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take $X = [0,1]$, $X_n = [1/n, 1]$, and $E = \{0,1\}$.  Then $d_H(X_n, X) = 1/n$ but $X\cap E = \{0,1\}$ and $X_n \cap E = \{1\}$ for all $n$, so $d_H(X_n \cap E, X \cap E) = 1$ for all $n$.

Comment: I know only a counterexample has been asked for, but if you could explain "intuitively"
 why this counterexample works, keeping in mind why OP thinks the given statement is true, then it would be nice too! +1 It is always important to know how to come up with counterexamples, and teaching that is sometimes more important than the counterexample itself.